# What does プチプチ mean?

Tags: word-choice

I thought that it might be a sound, but it may also mean bubble wrap. I just want to clarify. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

プチプチ{HLLL} is an onomatopoeia for the sound when bubbles (or something swollen) pop continually. It's reduplication of プチ（っと）.

プチプチ{LHHH} is the most well-known name of bubble wrap or [気泡緩衝材](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B0%97%E6%B3%A1%E7%B7%A9%E8%A1%9D%E6%9D%90) (although it's a brand name). Obviously it's named after the onomatopoeia.